# Dividing an interval into n equal parts in C++

Tags: c++, double

I'm having an issue with floating point arithmetic in c++ (using doubles) that I've never had before, and so I'm wondering how people usually deal with this type of problem.

I'm trying to represent a curve in polar coordinates as a series of Point objects (Point is just a class that holds the coordinates of a point in 3D). The collection of Points representing the curve are stored in a vector (of Point*). The curve I'm representing is a function r(theta), which I can compute. This function is defined on the range of theta contained in [0,PI]. I am representing PI as 4.0*atan(1.0), storing it as a double.

To represent the surface, I specify the desired number of points (n+1), for which I am currently using n=80, and then I determine the interval in theta required to divide [0,PI] into 80 equal intervals (represented by n+1=81 Points). So dTheta = PI / n. dTheta is a double. I next assign coordinates to my Points. (See sample code below.)

```
double theta0 = 0.0; // Beginning of inteval in theta
double thetaF = PI; // End of interval in theta
double dTheta = (thetaF - theta0)/double(nSegments); // segment width

double theta = theta0; // Initialize theta to start at beginning of inteval

vector<Point*> pts; // Declare a variable to hold the Points.

while (theta <= thetaF)
{
  // Store Point corresponding to current theta and r(theta) in the vector.
  pts.push_back(new Point(theta, rOfTheta(theta), 0.0));

  theta += dTheta; // Increment theta
}
```

rofTheta(theta) is some function that computes r(theta). Now the problem is that the very last point somehow doesn't satisfy the (theta <= thetaF) requirement to enter the loop one final time. Actually, after the last pass through the loop, theta is very slightly greater than PI (it's like PI + 1e-15). How should I deal with this? The function is not defined for theta > PI. One idea is to just test for ((theta > PI) and (theta < (PI+delta))) where delta is very small. If that's true, I could just set theta=PI, get and set the coordinates of the corresponding Point, and exit the loop. This seems like a reasonable problem to have, but interestingly I have never faced such a problem before. I had been using gcc 4.4.2, and now I'm using gcc 4.8.2. Could that be the problem? What is the normal way to handle this kind of problem? Thanks!

Comment: Your while loop could go for the number of segments.  Not sure that would fix all of your problems because pts having a value greater than  thetaF could potentially cause issues down the road.

Comment: Do not increment theta by dTheta in your loop. Calculate theta directly from the segment number you are in, eg. 'theta = theta0 + n*dTheta'. Hppe it will help, but will not remove problems with floating points in general.

Comment: That's exactly the next point I was getting ready to type.  Not sure if it will help but it's what I'd try.

Comment: Thanks, setting theta = theta0 + n*dTheta works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never iterate over a range with a floating point value (theta) by adding increments if you have the alternative of computing the next value by

```
theta = theta0 + idx*dTheta.
```

Control the iteration using the integer number of steps and compute the float as indicated.

If dTheta is small compared to the entire interval, you'll accumulate errors.

Answer (score 1):

You may not insert the computed last value of the range[theta0, thetaF]. That value is actually theta = theta0 + n * (dTheta + error). Skip that last calculated value and use thetaF instead.

Answer (score 0):

What I might try:

```
while (theta <= thetaF)
{
  // Store Point corresponding to current theta and r(theta) in the vector.
  pts.push_back(new Point(theta, rOfTheta(theta), 0.0));

  theta += dTheta; // Increment theta
}

if (theta >= thetaF) {
  pts.push_back(new Point(thetaF, rOfTheta(thetaF), 0.0));
}
```

you might want to cehck the if statement with `pts.length() == nSegments`, just experiment and see which produces the better results.

Comment: This might work for the specific number of iterations and value of `thetaF` given in the question, but it will fail in other cases where there happens to be rounding down instead of up, so that `theta` is slightly **less** than `thetaF` in the last desired iteration instead of **greater** than it. In that case, the first loop will exit after the desired number of iterations, and the following code will add an undesired point.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: get rid of the naked pointer :-)

You know the number of segments you have, so instead of using the value of theta in the while-block:

```
for (auto idx = 0; idx != nSegments - 1; ++idx) {
    // Store Point corresponding to current theta and r(theta) in the vector.
    pts.emplace_back(theta, rOfTheta(theta), 0.0);

    theta += dTheta; // Increment theta
}

pts.emplace_back(thetaF, /* rOfTheta(PI) calculated exactly */, 0.0);
```

Comment: Votes down are easily changed. And, while this is better, it does accumulate error in `theta` from iteration to iteration.

Comment: True, but I'd rather have my error pointed out to be so I can fix it.

Comment: Sorry, the voting guidelines indicate to vote based on the contents of the answer, not on their prospective future contents or the preferences of the author.

Comment: Btw, the accumulating error is certainly correct. However, when working with floating point values it's generally unavoidable. For starters, the value for  `PI` is obviously incorrect. Also, the question sounds to me like he's trying to draw a simple curve. If this is true, then the number of segments will be limited and precision error won't be really important. I'd probably go with `float` if he's indeed trying to draw a curve.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there would be 81 values of `theta`, then why not run a `for` loop 81 times?

```
int i;
theta = theta0;

for(i = 0; i < nSegments; i++) {
    pts.push_back(new Point(theta, rOfTheta(theta), 0.0));
    theta += dTheta;
}
```

Comment: The problem states that, not only does `theta` end up greater than `thetaF` (equal to `PI`) when calculated by incrementing it with `dTheta`, but that `rOfTheta` is not defined for arguments exceeding `PI`. So this code gets the iteration count correct but calls a function with an unacceptable argument value.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < nSegments; ++i)
{
    theta = (double) i / nSegments * PI;
    …
}
```

This:

- produces the correct number of iterations (since the loop counter is maintained as an integer),
- does not accumulate any error (since `theta` is calculated freshly each time), and
- produces exactly the desired value (well, `PI`, not π) in the final iteration (since `(double) i / nSegments` will be exactly one).

Unfortunately, it contains a division, which is typically a time-consuming instruction.

(The loop counter could also be a `double`, and this will avoid the cast from to `double` inside the loop. As long as integer values are used, the arithmetic for it will be exact, until you get beyond 2<sup>53</sup> iterations.)